# Parsing HTML between tags with Nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

Here's what my HTML file looks like:

```
<a href='http://crossfitquantico.blogspot.com/' target='_blank'>CrossFit Quantico</a> - Quantico,&nbsp;VA<br />
<a href='http://www.crossfitcherrypoint.com' target='_blank'>CrossFit Cherry Point</a> - Havelock,&nbsp;NC<br />
<a href='http://crossfitpentagon.com/' target='_blank'>CrossFit Pentagon</a> - Washington,&nbsp;DC<br />
<a href='http://crossfitwtbn.blogspot.com/' target='_blank'>CrossFit WTBN</a> - Quantico,&nbsp;VA<br />
<a href='http://cfnewriver.blogspot.com/' target='_blank'>CrossFit New River</a> - Jacksonville,&nbsp;NC<br />
<a href='http://xfitmiramar.com' target='_blank'>CrossFit Miramar</a> - San Diego,&nbsp;CA<br />
<a href='http://www.crossfitfortmeade.com/' target='_blank'>CrossFit Fort Meade</a> - Odenton,&nbsp;MD<br />
```

I was able to extract the link content/copy and URL but I also need to extract the information that is between the end of `</a>` and the beginning of the next `<a>`, whatever is right before the `<br />`. For example, in the first line I need to extract `"Quantico,&nbsp;VA"`.

Here's part of my code where I extract part of the information that I need:
here is what I'm doing so far (once I get the page object I'll have a loop to run through each line of the html source code that I have in order to extract all of the data I need):

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.crossfit.com/cf-info/main_affil.htm")) 
if page.text != ""
    ## Get the URL and Name
    if page.css("a")[i] != nil
        name = page.css("a")[i].text
    else
        name = 'NA'
    end
    if page.css("a")[i] != nil
        url = page.css("a")[i]["href"]
    else
        url = 'NA'
    end
end if
```

Comment: This is a very crude way of parsing HTML. Anyway, you can split each line with '-' then in the array grab the last value and it will be what you are after.

Comment: Show relevant codes you used for extracting the URLs to give us more context

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We're not really concerned about your "newbieness", we just like good questions. You need to show a minimal sample of your code so we can see what you're missing. As is it seems like you're asking us to write it for you. Also, your HTML is malformed for what you're asking us. Instead of just the links and trailing break there should be wrapping tags, preferably `<html><body>...</body></html>`. Stack Overflow wants complete examples that demonstrate the problem when asking for help debugging.

Comment: I appreciate all the help on this. I'm sorry, didn't post my code because it was very basic, but I added part of my code to my question above. Thanks again!

Comment: You need to indent your code properly. That's one of the best debugging tips you'll ever encounter.

Answer (score 0):

Read through the [XML::Node](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node) and [XML::NodeSet](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet) documentation. The methods available are there to make it possible to navigate and extract nodes:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
<body>
<a href='http://crossfitquantico.blogspot.com/' target='_blank'>CrossFit Quantico</a> - Quantico,&nbsp;VA<br />
<a href='http://www.crossfitcherrypoint.com' target='_blank'>CrossFit Cherry Point</a> - Havelock,&nbsp;NC<br />
</body>
</html>
EOT

data = doc.search('a').map{ |link|
  link_href = link['href']
  link_text = link.text
  trailing_text = link.next_sibling.text
  {
    href: link_href,
    text: link_text,
    trailing_text: trailing_text
  }
}
```

`data` will contain:

```
data 
# => [{:href=>"http://crossfitquantico.blogspot.com/",
#      :text=>"CrossFit Quantico",
#      :trailing_text=>" - Quantico,\u00A0VA"},
#     {:href=>"http://www.crossfitcherrypoint.com",
#      :text=>"CrossFit Cherry Point",
#      :trailing_text=>" - Havelock,\u00A0NC"}]
```

---

Don't do this:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.crossfit.com/cf-info/main_affil.htm")) 
if page.text != ""
    ## Get the URL and Name
    if page.css("a")[i] != nil
        name = page.css("a")[i].text
    else
        name = 'NA'
    end
    if page.css("a")[i] != nil
        url = page.css("a")[i]["href"]
    else
        url = 'NA'
    end
end if
```

`if page.text != ""` doesn't really tell you what you want to know, which is whether there are links. Simply searching the document will tell you that.

You're searching the DOM for links each time you use `page.css("a")` which wastes CPU. Testing `page.css("a")[i] != nil` is a waste too. If you iterate over a syntactically-correct document containing links correctly you'll never have situations where you couldn't find a link because `search` or its act-alikes will have handed them to you.

Here's a minor tweak to the above code to provide "NA" values:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <a href='http://crossfitquantico.blogspot.com/' target='_blank'>CrossFit Quantico</a> - Quantico,&nbsp;VA<br />
    <a href='http://www.crossfitcherrypoint.com' target='_blank'>CrossFit Cherry Point</a> - Havelock,&nbsp;NC<br />
    <a ></a>  
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc.search('a').class # => Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
doc.search('a').size # => 3

data = doc.search('a').map{ |link|
  link_href = link['href']
  link_text = link.text
  trailing_text = link.next_sibling.text
  {
    href: link_href || 'NA',
    text: link_text.empty? ? 'NA' : link_text,
    trailing_text: trailing_text
  }
}

data.size # => 3
data.class # => Array
data.first.class # => Hash

data 
# => [{:href=>"http://crossfitquantico.blogspot.com/",
#      :text=>"CrossFit Quantico",
#      :trailing_text=>" - Quantico,\u00A0VA"},
#     {:href=>"http://www.crossfitcherrypoint.com",
#      :text=>"CrossFit Cherry Point",
#      :trailing_text=>" - Havelock,\u00A0NC"},
#     {:href=>"NA", :text=>"NA", :trailing_text=>"  \n  "}]
```

Comment: Sorry to bother again but I'm able to extract the data for one single line of the html, but because I need to get the same data from the next line and so on I put the code above inside of a loop. However, how do I get to the next line using your example? On the code I had before I had a variable that was working as a counter which was convenient as I was using the children[counter] method... Pls advise. Thanks again!

Comment: The code in my example will iterate over *all* links in a document. It already is a loop; That's what `search('a').map{ |link| ... }` is doing. It returns an array of hashes containing the information from each link. See the added code.

Comment: Thank you very much! Appreciate it!